# How do I operate the server to compile/run a simple Fortran code?

Tags: ubuntu, fortran

I want to run a Fortran program on a server. I am able to log into that server using the command:

```
ssh -X username@I.P. address
```

I used `mkdir directoryname` command to create a directory.

Then I compile the Fortran source code  using

```
gfortran code.f90 -o code1
```

and  run it with the command:

```
./code1
```

This should start to compile the program. How do I know whether the process has started, is continuing and or has finished?

Please also tell me what does the commands `top`, `bg` and `kill PID number` mean.

Comment: Please try to ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your shell prompt doesn't reappear after running `./code1`, then your program is running. When your shell prompt comes back, your program has exited.

`top` is like the Task Manger on Windows or the Activity Monitor on macOS. It's a program that lets a user view and manipulate processes.

If you want to start your program in the background so that you have access to your shell when it's executing, run the program as `./code1 &`. Or, press `Ctrl+z` while the program is running to pause it and enter `bg` to resume it in the background.

You can kill (terminate) a program if you know its PID. The `kill` command actually sends signals to programs so you can do other things with it besides using it to tell programs to exit.

You can view a list of the processes currently running under your user account with `ps -u $USER`.

Comment: A background task may be signalled with its job ID. The job IDs are listed with the `jobs` command.  To kill job number 1, use `kill %1`.

Comment: dear @dsstorefile Thanks for the help. When the program runs in the background, how'll I know when it's finished?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 There will be a message in the terminal saying `Done`. This only appears after you press Enter though (as to not interfere with whatever you may be doing).

Comment: @Kusalananda When resumed in the background, is there a command which can tell me that the program is still running?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Yes, `jobs`. It will also be listed along with all other processes in `top`.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 If you start your process with `./code1 &` and then close the SSH session, your process is likely to be killed. Using `nohup ./code1 &` may get around this (allowing it to continue to execute) but [the first part of this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/463375/233915) suggests it might not be that simple...

Answer (score 1):

When running the program, use `./code1 &`, instead of `./code1`. Note 
the `&`. That signals that the given process must be run *asynchronously*. Henceforth, you can check on the progress of the 
program by running `ps`. If you want to cast back into the program, run `fg`.

Also, please make another question when another is desired.